# How to simplify SQL Code with IF condition. (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to simplify the below sql code without change the business logic.here I mentioned postgresql code that I want to modify.

```
SELECT IF(
    (SELECT `rate` FROM `vat_rate` WHERE '2017-05-12' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) is not null ,
    (SELECT `rate` FROM `vat_rate` WHERE '2017-05-12' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) ,

         IF((SELECT `rate` FROM `vat_rate` WHERE from_date is null and '2017-05-12' < to_date ) is not  null,
            (SELECT `rate` FROM `vat_rate` WHERE from_date is null and '2017-05-12' < to_date ),

                IF(
                    (SELECT `rate` FROM `vat_rate` WHERE to_date is null and '2017-05-12' > from_date) is not   null,
                          (SELECT `rate` FROM `vat_rate` WHERE to_date is null and '2017-05-12' > from_date),
                          'not found'
                         )
            )
    ) as rate
```

Comment: SQL has no `if` statement. And backticks are also illegal for SQL identifiers. Please [edit] your question and explain the actual _problem_ you are trying to solve (instead of throwing a bunch of invalid SQL at us) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Note: You can avoid this kind of mess by using -infinity and +infinity as default values for from_date and to_date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after the `Coalesce()` operator:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE (
    (SELECT rate FROM vat_rate WHERE '2017-05-12' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date),
    (SELECT rate FROM vat_rate WHERE from_date is null and '2017-05-12' < to_date ),
    (SELECT rate FROM vat_rate WHERE to_date is null and '2017-05-12' > from_date),
    'not found'
  ) as rate
```

Comment: Still not very efficient. As you can see the same table is used 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

The complexity is caused by allowing NULLs in the dates. Using `-infinity` and (+)`infinity` as the default values would have avoided the tests for NULL dates. Changing the table definition:

```
ALTER TABLE vat_rate
        ALTER COLUMN from_date SET DEFAULT '-infinity'
        , ALTER COLUMN to_date SET DEFAULT 'infinity'
        ;

UPDATE vat_rate SET from_date = DEFAULT WHERE from_date IS NULL;
UPDATE vat_rate SET to_date = DEFAULT WHERE to_date IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE vat_rate
       ALTER COLUMN from_date SET NOT NULL
       , ALTER COLUMN to_date SET NOT NULL
        ;
```

---

could reduce your query to just:

---

```
SELECT rate AS the_reet
FROM vat_rate
WHERE '2017-05-12' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
                ;
```

---

If you cannot change the table definition, you could fold the date values inside the query:

---

```
SELECT rate AS the_reet
FROM vat_rate 
WHERE '2017-05-12' BETWEEN COALESCE(from_date, '-infinity'::date)
                AND COALESCE(to_date, 'infinity'::date)
                ;
```

Avoiding the COALESCE() (this could be faster)

```
SELECT rate AS the_reet
FROM vat_rate 
WHERE ('2017-05-12' >=  from_date OR from_date IS NULL)
AND ( '2017-05-12' <= to_date OR to_date IS NULL)
                ;
```

The extreme case of *no matching range* could be solved by adding a union.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `CASE EXPRESSION` directly on the `vat_rate` table instead of selecting each value from it over and over? Here is a solution that should do the same using conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.val_1,t.val_2,t.val_3) as calc_col
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN vat_rate between  from_date AND to_date THEN rate END) as val_1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN from_date is null and '2017-05-12' < to_date THEN rate END) as val_2,
           MAX(CASE WHEN to_date is null and '2017-05-12' > from_date THEN rate END) as val_3
    FROM vat_rate) t
```